# Display Query Text from Snowflake inside Visual Studio, apart of Error (when executing dbt)?

Tags: visual-studio, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Is it possible/how would you go about displaying the query text that gets displayed inside Snowflake UI "history" tab inside of visual studio terminal?

I current have a local dev env (docker) that I use to write dbt (https://www.getdbt.com/) locally with and I can execute on against snowflake. The syntax is different in dbt than pure sql & harder to debug until sql text is visible once executed.  I have error messages, but would like to see the sql as well as it takes extra time to open up snowflake and look into the history and read the sql text that failed to complete.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Visual Studio Code for the project's development, you could supplement it with [dbt Power User](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=innoverio.vscode-dbt-power-user) plugin.

Features related to generated SQL code:

- "Generate a model from your source definition"
- "Visualize the result set of your model"
- "[See the compiled query of your model (Use CMD+' (mac) or CTRL+' (win))](https://github.com/innoverio/vscode-dbt-power-user#see-the-compiled-query-of-your-model-use-cmd-mac-or-ctrl-win)"

Answer (score 0):

Lukasz is right, and you should use the dbt Power User plugin. It's great.

But you don't need it to view compiled SQL.

When you run `dbt run` or any other command, dbt first executes a compilation step, and writes your compiled models to your `target` directory. You can view the compiled SQL for your model in `target/compiled/myproject/models/path/to/my/model.sql`.

The SQL that actually gets sent to your database is a little different, since your model SQL will be wrapped in some DDL, like `create table xyz as (...)`. You can also find that SQL in your project's target directory, `target/run/myproject/models/path/to/my/model.sql`.

dbt Power User is just navigating you to that file faster (which is nice!)